# How to set rootPage conditionally in Ionic3

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-native

I am trying to set a tutorial page for the first timers in the app and login page for others. I am setting key value in localstorage if user has been gone through the tutorial page.

```
export class MyApp {
rootPage: any = LoginPage;

constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
        statusBar.styleDefault();
        if(!localStorage.getItem( 'tutorial' )) {
            this.rootPage = TutorialPage;
        }
        splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }
}
```

Above code is working fine but there is a delay in setting the tutorial page and Login page is viewing first then Tutorial page is coming up. I want to know that am I doing this in the right way or I am missing something?

Comment: Remove `rootPage: any = LoginPage;` use only `rootPage: any;` and put `else` block in `constructor`.

Comment: Thanks @hrdkisback for your answer. it worked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please use following code

```
export class MyApp {
rootPage: any;

constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
        statusBar.styleDefault();
        if(!localStorage.getItem( 'tutorial' )) {
            this.rootPage = TutorialPage; // user can user this.nav.setRoot(TutorialPage);
        }else{
            this.rootPage = LoginPage; // user can user this.nav.setRoot(LoginPage);
        }
        splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }
}
```

i hope its work for you.